# Why do linq search has a huge difference in efficiency when I use string and array especially for large data?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to search the name of the students which contains the keywords,at first I pass the keywords separated by commas,but I find the search time is too long.But when I convert these keywords into an array,it is real fast.Why do linq search has a huge difference in efficiency?Is that because of the array or linq?

**Using string to search**

```
var keyWord="Lyly,Tom,Jack,Rose"; //and so on,more than 500 names
var student= Context.Students.Where(i => keyWord.Contains(i.Name));//very slow
```

**Using array to search**

```
var keyWord="Lyly,Tom,Jack,Rose"; //and so on,more than 500 names
 var keyWordArray=keyWord.split(',');
var student= Context.Students.Where(i => keyWordArray.Contains(i.Name));//fast
```

Comment: In your first example, we can't see how you pass from keyword string to stations collection

Comment: Thanks.I have update it.

Comment: Please, could you post a bit more of your code? Based on what we can see - and it's incomplete of course - I can tell you in the first example your code is applying the Contains function to a very large string, thus this could be easily a source of slowness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's because of the array. The Linq database provider can translate the one with array to a very efficient form.

Namely, in database termins,

the first query will use [SQL Like](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp), but the second query will use [SQL IN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx). The difference between those is massive.

the SQL Like has to do full scan over the whole string, in order to satisfy one student.

the SQL IN has to do no scans whatsoever, since `IN` is using sets under the cover.

Note that, this applies only to **databases**. If you would benchmark the above comparisions using `Linq2Object`, you'd probably wouldn't see any difference, maybe milliseconds.

If you want to make `Linq2Object` performant too, you should use `HashSet`, like so:

```
var keyWord = "Lyly,Tom,Jack,Rose";
var keyWordSet = new HashSet<string>(keyWord.split(','));

var students = Context.Students
                .ToList()
                .Where(i => keyWordSet.Contains(i.Name));
```

Comment: Hi,@Chris Eelmaa,Why does Linq2Object can not see any difference?But ronMan84 said the same difference would also occur in LINQ to Objects as well.

Comment: @Lyly: It can't see the difference because linq2objects is executed step by step, statement by statement. Contrast that with Linq2Sql that has overview of the WHOLE query, and can translate it to a more efficient SQL. The way Linq2Sql can see the "whole" linq query, is that they're using `IQueryable<T>` construct, opposite of `IEnumerable<T>` that Linq2Objects are using. Essentially, `Linq2Objects` is not "translating" anything, it is executing exactly what it has been told to do.

Comment: Hi,@Chris Eelmaa,The way Linq2Sql can see the "whole" linq query, is that they're using IQueryable<T> construct, opposite of `IEnumerable<T>` that Linq2Objects are using.Does it mean that `array` use `IQueryable<T>` and `HashSet` use `IEnumerable<T>`?

Answer (score 1):

The main difference is due to the query conversion, where `String.Contains` become `LIKE` and `List.Contains` becomes an `IN` (like @ChrisEelmaa said).

The same difference would also occur in LINQ to Objects as well, albeit with each occurring faster than what you have here (which is calling a database). `String.Contains()` goes through the *entire string* from start to finish and then returns whether or not it found something. In contrast, `List.Contains()` performs a completely linear search, and returns once it has found a match. Therefore, at most, `List.Contains()` will be the same speed, but for most elements it will be faster.

MSDN links for both:

[String.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

[List.Contains()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: IronMan84: It's not "same difference". `String.Contains()` stops as soon as it finds the match, there's no reason for it to go through the entire string if it found something. Why should it? They both perform linear search and stop as soon as possible. Also, notice that the call won't bind against `List.Contains()` when dealing with arrays.

Comment: The only difference is how each element is compared with the value being search for. In the first version of LINQ, it will stop as soon as characters don't match, however, the array one has extra benefit: it will "skip" the array elements that don't have the same length + same content, which will faster. The point is: the difference comes from the fact that Linq2Sql will be generating query that is using `set`, thus there will be no "linear search". On this example(using names), I am sure that the difference in Linq2Objects will be milliseconds.